# Epoch timestamp to UUID conversion in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, epoch, timeuuid

I want to convert a epoch time say **1639514232** to time UUID and save it to cassandra. `UUIDs.endOf()` is not working and generating a decipherable uuid **`5e23b68f-2cbb-11b2-7f7f-7f7f7f7f7f7f`** .
Can you suggest how can I achieve it.

Comment: `UUIDs.endOf()` does its work - you need to have random right part?

Comment: Perhaps a TimeUUID (type 1 UUID) might be better suited for this?

Comment: @Aaron You mean to say `val timeBasedUuid = UUIDs.timeBased` and which method to use to convert epoch to uuid ?

Comment: @AlexOtt I am using `UUIDs.endOf(accountCreateTime)` where accountCreateTime =1639514232 , its not working ;giving undecipherable time `5e23b68f-2cbb-11b2-7f7f-7f7f7f7f7f7f`